# ng-view and routing is not working

Tags: angularjs, ng-view

I've been struggling with using ng-view for my subview of my application. I've followed multiple tutorials and have even checked the routeProvider and locationProvider attributes to ensure that they were pointing to the correct path.

**index.html**

```
<html ng-app="elephantApp">
...
     <div id="view" ng-view>{{$scope.message}}</div>
...
</html>
```

**application.js**

```
/*
Main AngularJS for Elephant Blog App
```

*/

```
var elephantApp = angular.module("elephantApp", ["ngRoute", "ui.bootstrap"]); 

elephantApp.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider){ 
$routeProvider 
// Home 
.when('/', {
    templateUrl: "app/partials/home.html", 
    controller: "ElephantController"
})
.when('/about', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/about.html', 
    controller: 'PageCtrl'
}) ; 

$locationProvider

.html5Mode(true);
});

elephantApp.controller("ElephantController", function($scope, $route, $routeParams, $location){
    $scope.contentClass = 'content-home';

    $scope.message = {message: "Hi"}; 
}); 

elephantApp.controller("PageCtrl", function($scope, $route, $routeParams, $location){
    $scope.contentClass = 'content';
    $scope.model = {message: "Hey!"};
});

/*
function ElephantController($scope, $route, $routeParams, $location){
    $scope.contentClass = 'content-home';
     $scope.$route = $route;
     $scope.$location = $location;
     $scope.$routeParams = $routeParams;
     $scope.model = {message: "Hey"};

}
*/
```

So I have no idea what's going on at all.

I have even tried to do code like:

```
// Pages 
.when("/about", {templateUrl: "partials/about.html", controller: "PageCtrl"}) 
.when("/faq", {templateUrl: "partials/faq.html", controller: "PageCtrl"}) 
.when("/contact", {templateUrl: "partials/contact.html", controller: "PageCtrl"})

// Blog 
.when("/blog", {templateUrl: "partials/blog.html", controller: "BlogCtrl"}) 
.when("/blog/post", {templateUrl: "partials/blog_item.html", controller: "BlogCtrl"})

 // else 404 
 .otherwise("/404", {
    templateUrl: "partials/404.html", 
    controller: "PageCtrl"
 });
```

I would like to use the above code as it is what I mainly want to do. Though it isn't working. The ng-includes work but not my ng-views. Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, a route in angular is the hash in the URI path after #, for example `http://app/#/about`. By setting `$locationProvider.html5Mode` to true how you done, we can write without # `http://app/about`, but need that server always returning index.html. For this purposes you can use, for example, Express server: http://www.seankenny.me/blog/2013/08/05/angularjs-in-html5-mode-with-expressjs/

Comment: I see that. Though for some reason my ng-view is getting commented out.

Comment: Okay, so I figured it out. I had to comment out that `.html5Mode(True)` and now it works (for just the homepage. Though what you said makes sense, I am running a PHP Server and get a wrong routing scheme when I click on my about page. I'll have to find one, thanks!

Comment: Lastly, if I can do HTML5 mode, I would really like to. Do I need to set the base href and then do something like the Express example you provided but a PHP way?

Comment: May be one of them solutions will be useful for server side rewrites urls: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at it tomorrow. This has been very helpful. I thought I had already setup the Apache Rewrite but looking at my configuration, it isn't set that way anymore. I guess I lost it when I reformatted. Thanks.